# Cannot get meteor.js to return mongo collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I am trying to return a mongoDB database value to a template in my Meteor.js project.  The code that I am using is below.

```
Template.ResourceManager.helpers({
BoosterOneFuel : function(){
        return resources.findOne({system : "booster1"}).fuel;
}

});
```

However, this always returns null.  When I try to alert it, the alert also says that this value is null.  Mongo can find it when I run this line in the console while running ***meteor mongo***:

```
db.Resources.findOne({system : "booster1"}).fuel;
```

But meteor cannot.  (This is on a localhost, so meteor mongo should affect meteor's database)

I don't think its a problem with meteor loading before mongo does, because the following still doesn't work :

```
if(resource.find({system : "booster1"}))
     alert(resources.findOne({system : "booster1"}).fuel);
```

Anybody know whats going on here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the spelling? I see `Resources`, `resources`, `resource`...

Comment: are you subscribing to the resources collection on the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the collection is actually called `resources` - i.e. you have something that looks like:

```
resources = new Mongo.Collection('Resources');
```

Then it sounds like you just need to publish the documents to the client:

**server/publishers.js**

```
Meteor.publish('resources', function() {
  return resources.find();
});
```

**client/subscriptions.js**

```
Meteor.subscribe('resources');
```

Of course the subscription could happen in your template or router instead of globally, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Also note you should add a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) to your helper. For example:

```
Template.ResourceManager.helpers({
  BoosterOneFuel : function() {
    var b1 = resources.findOne({system : "booster1"});
    return b1 && b1.fuel;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey David.... I'm following the tutorial for version 1.5 (Collection section).  I have the same issue. Don't know what's wrong. Query in meteor console shown the document. Is there a way to debug this since browsers don't show errors here...?

Comment: Without more context I'm not sure what to suggest. Are you sure your helper (or whatever function is referencing the collection) is getting called?

Comment: I fond something. I don't fully understand `import` I guess. Tutorial said to add `import '../imports/api/tasks.js';` in client/server main.js. I altered this to `import {Tasks} from '../imports/api/tasks.js'` and it solved it.